# What is the form of an electrical oscillator Hamiltonian?

Tags: energy, electricity, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator in my search results when I search for "electrical oscillator Hamiltonian" and some other things too. But none of them answer my question about the form of the kinetic and potential energies of an electrical oscillator.

Searching for the kinetic energy and potential energy does not show up fruitful either such as [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Oscillations/15.03%3A_Energy_in_Simple_Harmonic_Motion). I am specifically looking for an *electrical* oscillator Hamiltonian.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "electric oscillator"? An [LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit)?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Yes, like an LC circuit. But more fundamentally, any electrical oscillation that involves charges that exhibit harmonic oscillation including their electric and magnetic fields to be described as varying with time. I don't want the Hamiltonian to be tied to any specific circuit but a general electrical oscillation as mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first consider a simple [LC-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit):
[image]
With some good will you can call the energy in the inductor kinetic energy,
and the energy in the capacitor potential energy.
$$E_\text{kin}=\frac{1}{2}LI^2$$
$$E_\text{pot}=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$
where $I$ is the current through the inductor
and $V$ is the voltage across the capacitor.
And the total energy (or Hamiltonian) becomes
$$E_\text{tot}=\frac{1}{2}LI^2+\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$

For more complicated circuits (with more inductors and capacitors)
you will need to sum over all of them.
You also need to consider [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) to account for
constraints, and thus reduce the number of independent degrees of freedom.
$$E_\text{tot}=\sum_L\frac{1}{2}LI_L^2+\sum_C\frac{1}{2}CV_C^2$$

In the most general scenario the total energy (or Hamiltonian) is the
[magnetic field energy and electric field energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html) integrated over all space.
$$E_\text{tot}
 = \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\int\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t)^2\ d^3r
 + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)^2\ d^3r$$

This formula is applicable to all static and dynamic electromagnetic
fields. The oscillating LC circuit from above is just a special case of it.

[image]
<sub>(animation from [LC circuit - Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#Operation))</sub>

Comment: Is it possible for someone to write the last total energy you wrote down (the most general scenario for the total energy) with changing or varying $B$ and $E$ fields with respect to time or can that information be included in the $B$ and $E$ fields themselves?

Comment: @Tachyon I don't understand what you ask. The Hamiltonian does not contain $\dot E$ and $\dot B$, if this is what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that the Hamiltonian you gave me seems to be applicable only for static $E$ and $B$ fields, thus not an oscillator. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Tachyon No, it is applicable for dynamic fields too. See my additon at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am curious about what you think of this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768142/231892 and how it relates to yours.

Comment: Follow up: do you know of any resources where I could find examples of time-dependent and radial-dependent $E$ and $B$ fields for a finite straight wire? Just like the ones you wrote in your last equation for the total general energy.

Answer (score 1):

The standard electrical osciallator is the Hertz dipole.

[image]

The Lagrangian of two  opposite point charges $\pm q(t)$, connected with a wire or coil at distance $d$  and a current in the (nearly) superconducting wire j(t) = dq(t)/dt=q' in the quasistatic approximation (no radiation, no resistance) is simply given by two constants, capacitance $C \frac{J}{(A s)^2}$ and inductance $L \frac {J}{A^2}$.

The product $L C \frac{1}{s^2}$  yields the time constant squared of the oscillation.

$$\mathcal L =\frac{ L}{2} \, q'^2(t) - \frac{1}{ 2\, C }\, q^2   $$

with $p =\partial_{q'} \mathcal L = L q' $  the canonical momentum variable, one has the Hamilton function

$$\mathcal H = \frac{1}{2\, L} p^2 + \frac{1}{ 2\, C }\, q^2 $$

Radiation can be neclegted for a dipol length small compared to the free air wavelength. Then inductance L and capacity C of the system are constants to represent all electromagnetic energy in the system.

For any system of point charges and currents L and C are symmetric matrices whose product matrix yields all eigenfrequencies.

In the simple case of the Hertz dipolt the formula for the eigenfrequency

$$  \omega\, = \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{L\, C}}$$

Answer (score 1):

[Write](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1703938) the Kirchhoff loop equations for $n$ independent meshes with impressed voltages $V_i^s(t)$ and currents $\dot q_i(t)$ in th e$i^{th}$ mesh and $[C],[R],[L]$ positive symmetric matrices in the form
$$V_i^s(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} [C_{ik}^{-1} q_k(t)+R_{ik} \dot q_k(t)+L_{ik}\ddot q_{k}(t)] \tag{1}$$
The associated Lagrangean is defined by

$$\mathcal L(q, \dot q, V^s) =-\tfrac12  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} C_{ik}^{-1} q_iq_k +\sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i^s q_i+ \tfrac12  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} L_{ik}\dot q_{k}\dot q_{k}(t) \tag{2}$$

with the dissipation function
$$\mathcal D(\dot q) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} R_{ik}\dot q_i \dot q_k \tag{3}$$
satisfies the Euler-Lagrange differential equations (4) and it is the same as the KVL Equation (1):

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q_i} -\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot q_i} =\frac{\partial \mathcal D}{\partial \dot q_i} \tag{4}.$$

Now let the *flux* $\Phi_i$ in the $i^{th}$ mesh be the Hamiltonian conjugate to $q_i$:
$$\Phi_i=\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot q_i} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}L_{ik}  \dot q_k \tag{5},$$ which can be inverted as

$$\dot q_i= \sum_{k=1}^{n}L_{ik}^{-1}  \Phi_k \tag{6},$$ with which we can define the *Hamiltonian* as
$$\mathcal H(q, \Phi, V^s)= - \mathcal L + \sum_{i=1}\dot q_i \Phi_i \\
=\tfrac12 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum C_{ik}^{-1}q_i q_k 
+\tfrac12 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum L_{ik}^{-1}\Phi_i\Phi _k 
-\sum_i V_i^sq_i \tag{7}.$$

Th energy dissipation can be expressed in the Hamiltonian formalism as follows:
$$2\mathcal D = \sum_{i=1}^n V_i^s \dot q_i - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\mathcal H + \sum _{i=1}^n V_i^s q_i\right)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(A_i\dot q_i +B_i \dot \Phi_i \right)\tag{8}$$
with the definitions
$$A_i=-\sum_{k=1}^n C_{ik}^{-1}q_k + V_i^s\\
B_i=-\sum_{k=1}^n L_{ik}^{-1}\Phi_k \tag{9}.$$

This is now completely symmetrical in the conjugate variables $q, \Phi.$ The special case of an ideal $LC$ resonator is when $n=1$, $R=0, \mathcal D = 0.$

Comment: So this is the most general case of them all then? With $n$ meshes and you are able to set any number of resistances, inductances, and capacitances with the corresponding currents and voltages. Is that correct?

Comment: I cannot speak for this being *the* most general case; all I can say is that for an $RLC$ linear network containing voltage sources Eqs (2), the Lagrangean, and (7), the Hamiltonian, recovers the KVL. Note that this setup covers magnetic coupling (ie., magnetic transformer) but does not include gyrators and other nonreciprocal elements, also is excluded ferromagnetic hysteresis, etc. I should also note that in a Hamiltonian sense $\Phi$ represents the EM kinetic *momentum* that is conjugate to the "displacement" $q$ instead of the "velocity" $\dot q$ that is showing up in the Lagrangean.